# Consulta sobre trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

una consulta estoy empezando con trigger y quisiera saber como usa las condicionales dentro de este, tengo esta base

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy vendiendo articulos e hice un trigger para que disminuya el stock cada vez que vendo , pero si el stock llega a 0 como podría hacer para que no haga la venta o me de un mensaje?

```
 ALTER trigger [dbo].[ventas]
 on [dbo].[venta]  for insert
 as 
 set nocount on

 update productos set  productos.stock=productos.stock-inserted.cantidad 
 from inserted
 inner join productos on productos.Cod_producto=inserted.cod_prod 

 insert into venta  values (8,3,140,299,11)
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas modificar el trigger. Se puede quedar como un simple `UPDATE`

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ventas ON dbo.venta
FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE p
  SET  
      stock = p.stock - i.cantidad
FROM   inserted i
INNER JOIN productos p ON p.Cod_producto = i.cod_prod;
GO
```

Lo único que necesitas hacer es crear un constraint en tu columna.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Productos ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Stock CHECK(stock >= 0);
```

Inclusive si quieres puedes usar TRY para crear errores personalizados.

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO venta
    VALUES( 8, 3, 140, 299, 11);
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 547
        RAISERROR( 'La venta supera el stock del producto', 16, 0);
    ELSE
        THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar **for**, podrías usar **instead of**... esto hace que no se ejecute la instrucción que haya ejecutado el trigger(en este caso la inserción)... Aprovechando eso puedes controlar antes de que haga la inserción con la condicional que verifique si la cantidad que se desee comprar existe dentro del stock... Si la diferencia entre el stock y la cantidad es menor o igual a cero entonces no se debería permitir insertar ningun nuevo registro en la tabla *venta*, si es mayor entonces que primero haga la inserción en la tabla *venta*(la que ejecuto el trigger) y luego la actualización del stock dentro de la tabla *productos*:

Llena en el lugar de los comentarios con el código que corresponda:

```
create trigger ejemplo
on venta
instead of insert
begin
    declare @stock int
    set @stock = (select stock from productos where cod_producto = inserted.cod_prod)

    declare @cantidad int
    set @cantidad = (select cantidad from inserted)

    if(( @stock - @cantidad) <= 0)
        --aquí pones el código que desees que se ejecute si no existe el stock
    else
    begin
        -- Aquí va la inserción que hayas hecho para que el trigger se ejecute  
        -- y aquí la actualización de la tabla productos
    end
end
```

Comment: Me sale error  en (inserted.cod_prod) - inserted.cantidad)

Comment: Se más detallista... Que error te sale?... Pon tu trigger completo

Comment: hay subi la foto

Comment: Asigna *inserted.cod_prod* y *inserted.cantidad* a variables para que puedas trabajar mejor... (hazlo obteniendo los valores con sus respectivos select)

Comment: hice una modificación en el código de la respuesta agregando lo que te dije